# Encrypt email body with mail-gpg gem on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, encryption, pgp

I'm trying to understand pgp encryption using the mail-gpg ruby gem for ruby on rails, while i made it work and both encryption and decryption work, they don't quite satisfy me as decrypting the pgp message reveals that information i don't want to send is also being encrypted.

Code:

```
  class EncryptMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def encrypted_mail user
        mail to: "#{user.email}", subject: 'Hopefully this is encrypted', content_type: 'text/plain', gpg: { encrypt: true, keys: { "#{user.email}" => user.pgp_key}}
    end
  end
```

Mail view:

```
Welcome to example.com
You have successfully signed up to example.com.
To login to the site, just follow this link: example.com
Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

Output after decryption

```
Date: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:44:26 -0500
From: from@example.com
To: to@example.com
Message-ID: <5a04be2ad575f_18982ab82f69def06728c@Personal_computer.mail>
Subject: Hopefully this is encrypted
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    Welcome to example.com
    You have successfully signed up to example.com.
    To login to the site, just follow this link: example.com
    Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

As visible the encrypted block message ends up having a bunch of extra information that I don't want. Is there any way to only encrypt the body of the email? Or am I better of just encrypting the mailer view outside of the mailer itself?

**UPDATE**

After taking a better look at the source code of the gem it seems that this was a deliberate choice by the author, it was however easy to implement an option to make the encryption only take the body. I've submitted the issue requesting permissions to do a pull request but in case it's never approved here's what I did.

In the gem's source code (which you can find [here](https://github.com/jkraemer/mail-gpg) ) Go to the encrypted_part.rb file and add this 2 lines of code inside the initialize method before the *encrypted* variable assignation

```
clean = options[:clean]
clean ? cleartext_mail = cleartext_mail.body : cleartext_mail
```

and that's it! You can now call on the *clean* option in the gpg call like this.

```
def encrypted_mail user
    mail to: "#{user.email}", subject: 'Hopefully this is encrypted', content_type: 'text/plain',  gpg: { encrypt: true, clean: true keys: { "#{user.email}" => user.pgp_key}
end
```

Comment: by output do you mean the mail source from your mail application ? Your decoded mail looks fine. It's just it's full email source with headers etc ... If you send an unencrypted email it will will look the same, don't think it's about encryption.

Comment: My mail application does return the headers and such but it also returns the encrypted block message to be decoded, with a private key and a passphrase with some other software. Doing so, shows the message that I referred as output, so i do think is incorrect. However this my first time ever dealing with encryption so you might be right.